# Question about series involving zeta function

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, zeta-functions

I was observing the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(2n+1)-1}{2n+1}$$
And Wolfram alpha says that it does not converge. But I'm convinced that this is wrong since $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\zeta(2n+1)-1) = \frac{1}{4}$$

I would imagine then, by comparison test, that the first series clearly converges. Am I wrong? If it does converge, do we have a value for it?

Comment: In your answer, what is supposed to be in the argument for the log? And no, I'm very certain that the parenthesis are fine. Wolfram isn't even telling me what test it used to show it doesn't converge.

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica (v10) returns `1/2 (2 - 2 EulerGamma - Log[2])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, since the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\left[\zeta(2n+1)-1\right]$ has bounded partial sums, the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\zeta(2n+1)-1}{2n+1}$ is convergent by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

By the integral representation for the $\zeta(s)$ function in the region $s>1$ (i.e. by the inverse Laplace transform) we have
$$ \zeta(2k+1) =\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\cdot \frac{dx}{e^x-1} $$
$$ \zeta(2n+1)-1 =\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\cdot \frac{dx}{e^x(e^x-1)} \tag{A}$$ 
$$ \frac{\zeta(2n+1)-1}{2n+1} =\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\cdot \frac{dx}{e^x(e^x-1)} \tag{B}$$ 
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\zeta(2n+1)-1}{2n+1} =\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sinh(x)-x}{x}\cdot \frac{dx}{e^x(e^x-1)} \tag{C}$$ 
and the RHS of $(C)$ equals $\color{red}{1-\gamma-\frac{1}{2}\log 2}\approx 0.07621$ by [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) and the integral representation for the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). Definitely a convergent series, and a curious bug of WA.

Comment: Wonderful! But how, may I ask, were you able to solve the final integral?

Comment: @RyanGoulden: I wrote *how*: Frullani's theorem and the integral representation for $\gamma$. You can also follow Olivier's approach, leading to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. The convergence may be obtained by the comparison test using, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{\zeta(2n+1)-1}{2n+1}\sim \frac{\frac1{2^{2n+1}}}{2n+1}
$$ a closed form of the sum may be obtained by integrating the standard series
$$
\psi(1+z)+\psi(1-z)= -2\gamma -2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \zeta (2k+1) z^{2k}, \qquad |z|<1,
$$ where $\psi$ denotes the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Taylor_series).

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Couldn't I just use the fact that the second series I wrote converges, to show that the first does? And I don't follow the second part of your answer.

Comment: You are right, one has $$ \left|\frac{\zeta(2n+1)-1}{2n+1} \right|\le\left|\zeta(2n+1)-1\right| $$ for $n\ge1$, giving the convergence of the first series.

Comment: (+1) and [congratulations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27491/44121).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you. I very much appreciated your congratulations.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I can fill in the missing details for you to help show how
$$I = \int^\infty_0 \frac{\sinh x - x}{x} \cdot \frac{dx}{e^x (e^x - 1)} = 1 - \gamma - \frac{1}{2} \ln (2).$$

To do this we will follow Jack's suggestion and use Frullani's theorem together with the following [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Integrals) for the Euler-Mascheroni constant of
$$\gamma = \int^\infty_0 \left (\frac{1}{e^x - 1} - \frac{1}{x e^x} \right ) \, dx.$$

We begin by observering that
$$\frac{1}{e^x (e^x - 1)} = \frac{1}{e^x - 1} - \frac{1}{e^x}.$$
So the integral can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
I &= \int^\infty_0 \frac{\sinh x - x}{x} \left (\frac{1}{e^x - 1} - \frac{1}{e^x} \right ) \, dx\\
&= \int^\infty_0 \left [\frac{\sinh x - x}{x (e^x - 1)} - \frac{\sinh x - x}{x e^x} \right ] \, dx\\
&= \int^\infty_0 \left [\frac{\sinh x}{x(e^x - 1)} - \frac{1}{e^x - 1} - \frac{\sinh x}{x e^x} + \frac{1}{e^x} \right ] \, dx\\
&= \int^\infty_0 \left [\frac{\sinh x}{x(e^x - 1)} - \frac{1}{e^x - 1} - \frac{\sinh x + 1}{x e^x} + \frac{1}{xe^x} + e^{-x} \right ] \, dx\\
&= -\int^\infty_0 \left (\frac{1}{e^x - 1} - \frac{1}{x e^x} \right ) \, dx + \int^\infty_0 e^{-x} \, dx + \int^\infty_0 \left [\frac{\sinh x}{x(e^x - 1)} - \frac{\sinh x + 1}{x e^x} \right ] \, dx\\
&= -\gamma + 1 + \int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{x} \left [\frac{\sinh x}{e^x - 1} - \frac{\sinh x + 1}{e^x} \right ] \, dx\\
&= 1 - \gamma + I_\alpha.
\end{align*}

Now for the term appearing in the square brackets of the integral, it can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sinh x}{e^x - 1} - \frac{\sinh x + 1}{e^x} &= \frac{e^x \sinh x - (e^x - 1)(\sinh x + 1)}{e^x (e^x - 1)}\\
&= \frac{\sinh x - e^x + 1}{e^x (e^x - 1)}\\
&= \frac{\frac{1}{2} (e^x - e^{-x}) - e^x + 1}{e^x (e^x - 1)}\\
&= -\frac{e^{-2x} - 2e^{-x} + 1}{2(e^x - 1)}\\
&= -\frac{(1 - e^{-x})^2}{2 e^x (1 - e^{-x})}\\
&= \frac{e^{-2x} - e^{-x}}{2}.
\end{align*}

Now as
$$I_\alpha = \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-2x} - e^{-x}}{x} \, dx,$$
is of the form of a Frullani integral, namely
$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{f(ax) - f(bx)}{x} \, dx = (f(0) - f(\infty)) \ln \left (\frac{b}{a} \right ),$$
where $f(x) = e^{-x}, a = 2, b = 1$, as $f(0) = 1$ and $f(\infty) = 0$ we have
$$I_\alpha = \ln \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ) = -\ln (2).$$
Thus
$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sinh x - x}{x} \cdot \frac{dx}{e^x (e^x - 1)} = 1 - \gamma - \frac{1}{2} \ln (2),$$
and is all thanks to Jack and his amazing insight!

Comment: I appreciate the response and explanation. Could you pleas explain how he went from his first step, however, to the second one. When he subtracted 1 from the left side, and was able to make it $\frac{1}{e^x(e^x -1)}$.

Comment: Never mind I see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The $\ds{\zeta}$-function is related to the *Digamma Function* $\ds{\Psi}$ by means of a [Generating Function: See $\ds{\mathbf{\color{black}{6.3.15}}}$ in A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm). Namely,
\begin{align}
&\left.\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\bracks{\zeta\pars{2n + 1} - 1}z^{2n}
\,\,\right\vert_{\ \verts{z}\ <\ 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2z} - {1 \over 2}\,\pi\cot\pars{\pi z} - {1 \over 1 - z^{2}} + 1 - \gamma - \Psi\pars{1 + z}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\gamma}$ is the
*Euler-Mascheroni Constant*. Then,
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\zeta\pars{2n + 1} - 1 \over 2n + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\left[{1 \over 2z} - {1 \over 2}\,\pi\cot\pars{\pi z} - {1 \over 1 - z^{2}} + 1 - \gamma\right.
\\ &\ \phantom{= \int_{0}^{1}}
\left.\vphantom{1 \over 2z}
-\Psi\pars{1 + z}\right]\dd z
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{1 - \gamma - {1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2}} \\ &
\end{align}
Similarly,
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{\zeta\pars{2n + 1} - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{z \to 1}\left[{1 \over 2z} - {1 \over 2}\,\pi\cot\pars{\pi z} - {1 \over 1 - z^{2}} + 1 - \gamma\right.
\\[2mm] &\
\phantom{\lim_{z \to 1}\left[\right.}
\left.\vphantom{1 \over 2z}
-\Psi\pars{1 + z}\right] = \bbx{1 \over 4}
\\ &
\end{align}